# Create js clone a Shape with dynamically drawn graphics

Tags: createjs, easeljs

I have a Image on a stage and I'm drawing over it and erasing it. Using the following method

http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/ZNYPD/

Now i want to take a clone of the user drawings but its not working. I tried

```
 var drawingAreaClone = drawingArea.clone(true);
```

but its not working .

Is there a way to clone it. kindly Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demo you posted doesn't clear the stage, but instead clears the graphics each frame. If you clone the shape, it will have no instructions.

@Catalin's answer is right if you just need a visual -- but another option is to use the Graphics store() method instead of clearing the graphics: http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.html#method_store

Essentially this method just sets an internal pointer to where the graphics draw from. By storing after each draw, only future draw calls are made. This will have the same application as the demo you posted, only you can call `unstore()` later to reset the Graphics to draw from the beginning. If you clone it this way, it should work.

```
var erase = document.getElementById("toggle").checked;
wrapper.updateCache(erase?"destination-out":"source-over");
//drawing.graphics.clear();
drawing.graphics.store(); // Don't draw anything before this point

// Later
var newGraphics = drawing.graphics.clone();
newGraphics.unstore(); // Might be redundant
var shape = new Shape(newGraphics);
```

Note that cloning Graphics doesn't recreate the entire graphics tree, and simply clones the array that stores the instructions. Modifying the individual instructions after the fact would impact any clones of that Graphics object.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If the drawn line shape is a child of the `drawingAreaClone` then the clone should work properly.

However, if for some reason you can't make it work with that, you can take a snapshot of the canvas and save it as an `img` type varaible like this:

`var snapshot = new Image();
snapshot.src = canvas.toDataURL();`

Also, if you don't want to snapshot the whole canvas, after you saved the initial image, you can limit the drawing area to a `rectangle` with these extra instructions:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = snapshot.width;
canvas.height = snapshot.height;
ctx.drawImage(snapshot, rectangle.x, rectangle.y, rectangle.width, rectangle.height, 0, 0, rectangle.width, rectangle.height);
snapshot.src = canvas.toDataURL();
```